# Concatenating text from one cell into a function's range

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to have a function look up text from a specific cell and concatenate it to a row number to make a function dynamic since the range differs for each set of rows.

The non-dynamic formula is `=COUNTIFS(C2:EC2,"<>",C3:EC3,"")` but I would like to replace the starting column in the first range with text from `EJ2`. For example, `EJ2` equals "C". I've tried `=COUNTIFS(INDEX(EJ2,1)&"2":EC2,"<>",C3:EC3,"")`, which doesn't work, even though `INDEX(EJ2,1)&"2"` on its own gives me the desired "C2"

Ideally, I would like it to insert the text from whichever of two cells has a higher text value. To continue the example, `EJ2`=C and `EJ3`=D. Thus, the resulting range would be `D2:EC2` in the COUNTIFS function.

Screenshot of attempted function:

[image: IMG:]

Comment: Take a look at the [INDIRECT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/indirect-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261) function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step 1:** Find the max string from `EJ2:EJ3` (or whatever other one-dimensional array you want)

```
{=INDEX(EJ2:EJ3,MATCH(MAX(COUNTIF(EJ2:EJ3,"<"&EJ2:EJ3)),COUNTIF(EJ2:EJ3,"<"&EJ2:EJ3),0))}
```

<sup><sup>[Source](https://www.exceltip.com/lookup-formulas/finding-the-maximal-minimal-string-based-on-alphabetic-order.html)</sup></sup>
Enter this formula in some other cell. I put it in `A3` just because it was convenient. Be sure to enter it as an array formula. This means copy everything but the curly brackets `{  }`, paste it in the formula bar, and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. This should now give you the max string. It should work for any alphanumeric sting regardless of capitalization.

---

**Step 2:** Build the formula you want using the `INDIRECT` function

```
=COUNTIFS(INDIRECT(A3&"2:EC2"),"<>",INDIRECT(A3&"3:EC3"),"")
```

`INDIRECT` lets you build a reference to a range as a string and then returns that range. This means you can use its output in the `COUNTIFS` function.

Comment: Thanks, that sent me in the right direction. I need to learn a lot more about using ```INDIRECT```. In this situation, do I have to use it with the concatenation? I tried ```=COUNTIFS(INDIRECT(A3):INDIRECT(A4),"<>",INDIRECT(A5):INDIRECT(A6),"")``` where  A3 through A6 where cell references and it didn't work. I also unsuccessfully tried ```=COUNTIFS(INDIRECT(A3),"<>",INDIRECT(A5),"")``` where A3 and A5 were ranges that were concatenated separately

Comment: `INDIRECT` takes in a *string* and outputs a *range*. That's a big difference in Excel. You need to build the entire string inside the function. Instead of `INDIRECT(A3):INDIRECT(A4)`, try `INDIRECT(A3 & ":" & A4)` or, if you prefer, `INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(A3,":",A4))`. In your second example, I would expect the contents of `A3` to be something like `C2:EC2`.